# Removing AD Group members according to their memberships to certain groups in the same OU

Tags: script, powershell, active-directory

Our AD groups for Websense filtering has been set up with very little flexibility for policy management. There are only two groups for "Permit all" web browsing category. Now I need to create over 20 groups and add users to their own departments groups which HR provided me with. This is the easy part. But I need to delete these users from their old groups and make sure there are no multiple websense atributed group memberships.

I can't simply delete the old groups, there are a lot of users in there who have been given Internet privileges and not a member of the partial list HR provided me, result of weird corporate structure.

I am not an AD admin at all but you know the saying "somebody got to do it" :)

Help with scripts would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with PowerShell. First you need to look for users that are members of both the new and the old group and then you need to remove them from the old group:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$group1 = Get-ADGroup "group1"
$group2 = Get-ADGroup "group2"

$UsersToRemove = Get-ADUser -Filter { (memberof -RecursiveMatch $group1) -and (memberof -RecursiveMatch $group2) } 

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "group1" -Members $UsersToRemove
```